# qsort() invalid memory access

Tags: c

I have to take a number and return number in descendering order. I using qsort() function and yeld an Invalid memory access error. Also tried to do a sort function without using constant variables and it yield same error. What I am doing wrong?

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int cmp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
  return *(int *)a - *(int *)b;
}

uint64_t descendingOrder(uint64_t n)
{
  int digits = log10(n) + 1;
  int arr[digits];
  uint64_t out = 0;
  
  for(int i = 0; i < digits; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = n % 10;
    n /= 10;
  }
  
  qsort(arr, digits, sizeof(int), cmp);
  
  for (int i = digits - 1; i >= 0; i--)
  {
    out *= 10;
    out += arr[i];
  }
  
  return out;
}
```

Comment: Did you compile your code with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g`, and did you use the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger? At last, `qsort` is open source in [GNU libc](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/) and you can study its source code there... Did you read the documentation of [qsort(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html) ?

Comment: I'm trying solve a codewars challenge and don't have access to compiler or debugger. I realized that deleting function cmp() and qsort() call also it yield an invalid memory access error. Curious is that if a run this program in my own pc compiles and executes rightly.

Comment: Are you allowed to install a [Debian](https://debian.org/) distribution on your own PC? You then can install `gcc` and `gdb`. Perhaps you want to learn and use [Frama-C](https://frama-c.com/)

Comment: I'm using a Debian distribution on my PC

Comment: I can't reproduce this problem, even with strict sanitizers. As an aside, you will almost always only need `<stdint.h>` not `<inttypes.h>`.

Comment: Assuming you want to use `PRIu64` for output `<inttypes.h>` is fine and it includes `<stdint.h>`. (of course  you would need `stdio.h` as well) Your code is fine and the error is elsewhere in code you haven't shown.

Comment: I'm replicate the problem how is presented. By default `<inttypes.h>` is included. On my PC works fine and not yield errors using `-Wall` `Wextra` options. But in Codewars challenge not works. I would like know if any version of compiler can produce this error and how to solve it.

Comment: The code that I'm showing is the only code that I did, just that challenge not works.

Comment: Hmm, `descendingOrder(0)` would certainly be a problem with `log10(0)`.  Post input used.

Comment: Perhaps VLA support is broken.  Try `int arr[digits];` --> `int arr[20];` and verify `digits` in [1... 20] range.  Post a [mcve]

Comment: You're right. The problem was `log10(0)`. Thank you very much!

Comment: Agree with @chux-ReinstateMonica, having a simple check for `n` at the start of the function can avoid any issues like `log10(0)`, like `if (n == 0) return;`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Range**

Code lacks range check.  Below is a problem when `n == 0` as with `log10(0)` "A pole error may occur if the argument is zero".  If code continues, the value of `digits` may be *far* outside the expected 1 to 20 range.  Potential result: Invalid memory access error.

```
int digits = log10(n) + 1;
```

Instead check for edge cases.  [@
kiner_shah](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69951713/qsort-invalid-memory-access?noredirect=1#comment123654962_69951713)

```
if (n == 0) return 0;
int digits = log10(n) + 1;
```

---

**Overflow**

Math may overflow.  Using *unsigned* math will prevent *undefined behavior* here, yet the result is not valid.

```
descendingOrder(UINT64_MAX);
// result
6543945185896553020
// Hoped for result, yet outside uint64_t range.
98777665555444431110

if (out >= UINT64_MAX/10 && 
    (out > UINT64_MAX/10 || arr[i] >  UINT64_MAX%10)) {
  Handle_overflow();
}
out *= 10;
out += arr[i];
```

**Avoid floating-point code for an integer problem**

`log10(n)` first *rounds* the `uint64_t` to a `double`.  Consider

```
descendingOrder(1000000000000000000    ) --> 1000000000000000000
descendingOrder(1000000000000000000 - 1) --> 9999999999999999990
rather than the correct
999999999999999999
```

Use alternative code.  An example using [`snprintf()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/snprintf.html):

```
int digits = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%llu", (unsigned long long) n);
```